# Meteor server crashes very frequently without any error

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, amazon-ec2, nohup

I am working with the Meteor application and I deployed the same over EC2 instance. It was working fine till a few days back.

> But now the server process kill automatically without any error log or
>   console

I tried to get the error but unfortunately, as there are not any logs I am unable to find out why the server is crashing again and again.

I have a medium EC2 machine on which the application is running.

I am using **nohup** for running the application in the background.
Below is the command I used to start the server:-

> nohup meteor --settings SETTINGS-PRODUCTION.JSON &

I am wondering to know about **server crashes due to nohup or some other reason is there.**

Please let me know how we can console **uncaught exception** in the meteor-like we do in express.

> What should I use to auto restart the server if the process is killed
>   by any error or exception?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: is mongodb also running on the same ec2?

Comment: @Ankit thanks for your response, Yes MongoDB also running on the same ec2

Comment: do what @mikkel suggests in the answer. nohup is not to be used for production. Also try moving mongodb to other server or use cloud provider like mlab, compose or MongoDB atlas.

Comment: Getting error while using Mup.
 MongoError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]

Comment: ask a different question for this.

Answer (score 0):

Using `nohup` is quite a low-tech solution. Things like Phusion Passenger, PM2, or forever do a better job.

Also your docker container can be configured to automatically restart the process.

Even better is a tool called Meteor Up, which makes it really simple to deploy Meteor apps to EC2.

> EASILY DEPLOY YOUR APP Meteor Up is a production quality Meteor app
>   deployment tool.
>
> Install with one command:
>
> $ `npm install --global mup`

http://meteor-up.com/

Comment: Thanks for an update. I have setup mup as well.
But it's giving me the error of MongoDB connection.
 MongoError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]